# Create a function which return table value in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have problem in creating a function in Mysql.

1.I have to create a function which will get a input string which consists of date's in comma seperated value and i want to convert it into multiple date records through a function

please find the below sample input

```
set @value = '01-02-2017,01-03-2017,04-03-2017,07-03-2017,13-03-2017,14-03-2017,17-03-2017,18-03-2017,31-03-2017';
```

query that i have tried is shown below

```
delimiter $$
create function fn_split(value varchar(255)) 
returns int
begin
declare num int;
declare val int;
set num := 1;
set val := (select char_length(value)-char_length(replace(value,',','')));
create temporary table if not exists my_tab(date1 datetime);
delete from my_tab;
while num>val
insert into mytab (date1)
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',num);
set num = num + 1;
end while;
select count(date1) into count1 from my_tab;
return (count1);
end $
delimiter;
```

error that i am getting

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into mytab (date1) select SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',num); set num = num +' at line 11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the "select" before SUBSTRING_INDEX shouldn't be there.

Comment: how to insert the value into the table -- Nick

Comment: The INSERT should do that. Although the syntax is still wrong it should be `INSERT INTO mytab (date1) VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', num))`

Comment: Is my approach is correct to create a function for returning table value.

Comment: I think it's the easiest way in MySQL

Comment: use FIND_IN_SET(columnName,@value) to convert it into multiple date

Comment: @PankajKumar i think FIND_IN_SET()  is to get the position of the values passed in a given string